# Probability of at least one head given that there is at least one tail on three tosses of a fair coin

Tags: probability

> What is the probability of observing at least one head **given** that one observes at least one tail on three tosses of a fair coin.

This is a poorly worded question in my opinion and am leaning towards this is a trick question and the answer is simply 1/2. Am I missing any details? This is in a section discussing Bayes Rule and Theorem

Comment: It seems like a correctly worded question to me. The answer being one half seems unlikely since you are tossing three coins. A fairly easy way to deal with this particular problem is to just look at the probability space and see which outcomes are left (given that one observes at least one tail) then you can figure out the probability simply by counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be pretty quick to just list all possible outcomes.  There are 8 ways you can flip 3 coins.  Only one of them is eliminated by the condition (HHH).  How many of the remaining results have at least one head?

Answer (score 1):

This is a poorly worded question. I take it to mean: *what is the probability of observing at least one head out of three tosses, given that at least one of these tosses is a tail?* Turkeyhundt's answer is nice and intuitive, but I'll do it with the law of conditional probability.

Let $H$ be the number of heads and $T$ the number of tails. Note that $P(H \geq 1) = 1 - P(H=0)$.

Recall the law of conditional probability: $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
So
$$P(H \geq 1 | T \geq 1) = \frac{P(H \geq 1 \cap T \geq 1)}{P(T \geq 1)}$$
Which by our earlier observation is equal to:
$$P(H \geq 1 | T \geq 1) = \frac{P(H \geq 1 \cap T \geq 1)}{1 - P(T  = 0)}$$
Where $P(T = 0)$, by binomial probability and assuming the coin is fair, is $P(T=0) = {3 \choose 0} (1/2)^3(1/2)^0 = 1/8$. Thus:
$$P(H \geq 1 | T \geq 1) = \frac{P(H \geq 1 \cap T \geq 1)}{7/8}$$
Now, to find $P(H \geq 1 \cap T \geq 1)$, we should just list the possible sequences of coin tosses that would allow this (there are $8$ tosses). The conditions eliminate two possible sequences: $HHH$ and $TTT$. So $P(H \geq 1 \cap T \geq 1) = 6/8$. Whereby:
$$P(H \geq 1 | T \geq 1) = \frac{6/8}{7/8} = \frac{48}{56} = \frac{6}{7}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the random variable counting the number of heads in a toss of 3 coins. So, $X$ follows $B(3,\frac{1}{2})$.

Let $H'$ be the event that at least one of the two remaining tosses produces a heads and $H$ is the event that the first toss is a head.
So, we need $P(H'|H)$.
$\displaystyle P(H'|H)=\frac{P(H'\cap H)}{P(H)}=\frac{P(X\ge 2)}{P(H)}=\frac{1}{2}$.